# Why should I join two columns when I can do it in an easier way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So think that we’ve got two tables and in one of them, we’ve got our customers and the other has our orders in it and we’ve got a customer id in both of them.

[image: Customers Table]

So I want to get the orders of a specific customer and in here I’ve got two ways to do it:

1. I can say (Select * from orders where id = ‘1’
2. I can say (Select * from customers join orders on id = customers.id where id = ‘1’

So I’m asking this, why should I use the second method as it’s longer to write or are there any other uses to this?

Comment: The first method won't give you any customer details, or let you filter by any values in the customer table other than Id

Comment: Another reason why you would do this is to get the customers Name and/or shipping information. Usually the customer ID doesn't mean anything to most people. But if you don't want the information from the customer then no need to join the two.

Comment: The customer ID in the Orders table is called a Foreign Key (hopefully) and keeps referential integrity between the two table and most likely other tables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the customer id, then simply do:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.customer_id = 1;
```

You only need to join the tables together if you want to use other information, such as:

```
select o.*
from orders o join
     customers c
     on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
where c.email = @email;
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. 